# Meteor destroy subTemplate

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a parent template which calls a child template. I want to kill the child template by the press of a button.

Parent Template

```
    <template name="tracker">
         <span id="destroyChild" class="btn" title="destroyTable"></span>
    
         {{<child}}
    </template>
```

Then, I have an event to attempt and destroy the child template

```
'click span[id=destroyChild]'(e, template) {
            //This works to remove the Parent template
            //Blaze.remove(template.view);
 
           Blaze.remove('what do I put here?');
        },
```

I can't find anything to use as a param to remove the child template. I keep getting `Uncaught Error: Expected template rendered with Blaze.render`.

I gave the child template an Id and tried calling this with a `selector` but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the child automatically destroyed when it is not rendered into the DOM anymore?

Comment: I would think so, but what are you leading to?

Comment: I'm assuming in your code `{{<child}}` is actually `{{> child}}`, right?

Comment: I've never called `Blaze.remove` in five years of using Meteor and like Jan suggested you probably don't need to either. You should probably find a reactive way of doing this, i.e., guard the inclusion of the child with a condition that you then change on button click.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't imperatively modify your layout. Blaze is a reactive engine, so everything should be decided declaratively, e.g.:

```js
<template name="tracker">
   <span id="destroyChild" class="btn" title="destroyTable"></span>

   {{#if show}}
   {{> child}}
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

```
Session.setDefault('show', true);
Template.tracker.helpers({
  show() {
    return Session.get('show');
  }
});

...

  'click span[id=destroyChild]'(e, template) {
     Session.set('show', false);
  },
```